# SXA Search is unable to return result with '/' and/or '&' in Facet value

Tags: sxa

I have a sxa search component with multiple facets. In one of the facets, there is an entry that has a filter value of "Corporate / M & A". It yield no result when I choose the facet with that value.
[image]

I did play around on the filter text value and found out that the issue was the special characters '/' and '&'. Removing those characters yields results.

Is this an expected behavior in sxa search component? Would there be a work around for this scenario?

However. I did tried use the same search text to query directly in Solr and there was no issue. I was able to pull records.

sample solr query: solr_field:"Corporate / M & A" AND _language:"en"

sxa version: Sitecore Experience Accelerator 9.3.0.2589

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have managed to pinpoint what is causing the issue on not returning search result when a facet value includes "/" and "&" characters.

Decompiling Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.dll helped me to see the pipelines used in search and facet filtering.

The culprit was Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Pipelines.EncodeFacetValue.EscapeValue processor.

The processor looks like this:

```
public class EscapeValue : EncodeFacetValueProcessor
  {
    public override void Process(EncodeFacetValueArgs args)
    {
      args.EncodedValue = Uri.EscapeDataString(args.OriginalValue);
      args.EncodedValue = args.EncodedValue.Replace("%20", " ");
    }
  }
```

As seen in the code, the original facet value is being converted to its escaped representation. This is where the issue comes in.

Original value:
args.OriginalValue = "Corporate / M & A":

Encoded value:
args.EncodedValue = "Corporate%20%2F%20M%20%26%20A"

Final encoded value:
args.EncodedValue = "Corporate %2F M %26 A"

The final encoded value is returned and used as search filter. Search filter yields no result due to encoded special characters.

Workaround:

I created a custom pipeline and patch this pipeline replacing the original pipeline.

```
public class EscapeValue : EncodeFacetValueProcessor
{
     public override void Process(EncodeFacetValueArgs args)
     {
          args.EncodedValue = args.OriginalValue;
     }
}
```

As the intended value search filter is the args.OriginalValue, I just assigned that value to args.EncodedValue.

I did some testing to make sure nothing is impacted as for my project is concern and I didn't find any.

I am pretty sure that there is an explanation why the facet value is being converted to its escaped representation which I don't know the answer yet.

But in my case the workaround works fine.